# Html Quiz not working js questions not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fonts

So for a bigger project I decided to follow a course which was making a quiz so it was perfect for my bigger project. But for some reason the questions and the answers are not showing and all my jquery and js appear to be not working. I tried putting the functions above and below the code and still not working. I tried renaming the class name and still no response.Please help, thanks
Heres the html code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Baby animal names</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="quizContainer">
      <h1>Chooze the correct animal baby names!</h1>
      <div class="question"></div>
      <ul class="choiceList"></ul>
      <div class="quizMessage"></div>
      <div class="result"></div>
      <div class="nextButton">Next Question</div><br/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

The css:

```css
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat);
h1{
  font-family: 'Caveat', serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  font-family: 'Pacifico', serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #feb135;
}
input[type=radio]{
  border: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2em;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Caveat';
}

.quizContainer{
  background-color: #000398;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 190px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
}


.nextButton{
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Caveat', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.question{
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #f2f205;
  text-align: center;
  color: #27a63;
}
.quizMessage{
  background-color: peachpuff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: "Caveat";
  color: red;
}
.choiceList{
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  color: blueviolet;
}

.result{
  width: 30%;
  height:auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: linen;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Caveat';
}
```

And js:

```js
    var questions = [{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
},{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices:["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns:4
}];
var curruntQ = 0;
var correctA = 0;
var quizO = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  displayCurrentQuestion();
  $(this).find('.quizMessage').hide();
  $(this).find('.nextButton').on("click", function(){
    if(!quizO){
      value = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
      if(value == undefined){
        $(document).find(".quizMessage").text("Please select an answer");
        $(document).find(".quizMessage").show();
      }else {
        $(document).find(".quizMessage").hide();
        if (value == question[curruntQ].correctA){
          correctA++;
        }
        curruntQ++;
        if(curruntQ<question.length){
          displayCurrentQuestion();
        }else {
          displatScore();
          $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Take again!");
          quizO = true;
        }
      }
    }else {
      quizO = false;
      $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Next question");
      resetQuiz();
      displayCurrentQuestion();
      hideScore();
    }
  });
});
function displayCurrentQuestion() {
  console.log("On display current question")
  var question = questions[curruntQ].question;
  var questionClass = $(document).find(".quizContainer > .question");
  var choicesList = $(document).find(".quizContainer > .choicesList");
  var numChoices = questions[curruntQ].choices.length;
  $(questionClass).text(question);
  $(choicesList).find("li").remove();
  var choice;
  if (i = 0; i < choicesList; i++){
    choice = questions[curruntQ].choices[i];
    $('<li><input type="radio" value=' + i + ' name="dynradio"/>' + choice + '<li>').appendTo(choicesList);
  }
}function resetQuiz() {
currentQ = 0;
correctA = 0;
hideScore();
}

function displatScore() {
  $(document).find(".quizContainer > .result").text("You scored" + correctA + " out of: "+ questions.length);
  $(document).find(".quizContainer > .result").show();
}

function hideScore() {
  $(document).find(".result").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up `if` with `for` here:

```js
if (i = 0; i < choicesList; i++) {
    choice = questions[curruntQ].choices[i];
    $('<li><input type="radio" value=' + i + ' name="dynradio"/>' + choice + '<li>').appendTo(choicesList);
}
```

However, the `for` loop won't run, since `choicesList` isn't a number but an element. You mistaked it for `numChoices`.

You also made a typo. `$(document).find(".quizContainer > .choicesList");` should be `$(document).find(".quizContainer > .choiceList");` (no `s`).

Try this:

```js
var questions = [{
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}, {
  question: "What is the baby of a Moth",
  choices: ["baby", "infant", "kitt", "larva"],
  correctAns: 4
}];
var curruntQ = 0;
var correctA = 0;
var quizO = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  displayCurrentQuestion();
  $(this).find('.quizMessage').hide();
  $(this).find('.nextButton').on("click", function() {
    if (!quizO) {
      value = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
      if (value == undefined) {
        $(document).find(".quizMessage").text("Please select an answer");
        $(document).find(".quizMessage").show();
      } else {
        $(document).find(".quizMessage").hide();
        if (value == question[curruntQ].correctA) {
          correctA++;
        }
        curruntQ++;
        if (curruntQ < question.length) {
          displayCurrentQuestion();
        } else {
          displatScore();
          $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Take again!");
          quizO = true;
        }
      }
    } else {
      quizO = false;
      $(document).find(".nextButton").text("Next question");
      resetQuiz();
      displayCurrentQuestion();
      hideScore();
    }
  });
});

function displayCurrentQuestion() {
  console.log("On display current question")
  var question = questions[curruntQ].question;
  var questionClass = $(document).find(".quizContainer > .question");
  var choicesList = $(".choiceList");
  var numChoices = questions[curruntQ].choices.length;
  $(questionClass).text(question);
  $(choicesList).find("li").remove();
  var choice;
  for (i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) {
    choice = questions[curruntQ].choices[i];
    $('<li><input type="radio" value=' + i + ' name="dynradio"/>' + choice + '<li>').appendTo(choicesList);

  }
}

function resetQuiz() {
  currentQ = 0;
  correctA = 0;
  hideScore();
}

function displatScore() {
  $(document).find(".quizContainer > .result").text("You scored" + correctA + " out of: " + questions.length);
  $(document).find(".quizContainer > .result").show();
}

function hideScore() {
  $(document).find(".result").hide();
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat);
h1 {
  font-family: 'Caveat', serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #feb135;
}

input[type=radio] {
  border: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2em;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Caveat';
}

.quizContainer {
  background-color: #000398;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 190px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.nextButton {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Caveat', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.question {
  font-family: 'Caveat';
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #f2f205;
  text-align: center;
  color: #27a63;
}

.quizMessage {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: "Caveat";
  color: red;
}

.choiceList {
  font-family: 'Caveat';
}

.result {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: linen;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Caveat';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Baby animal names</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="quizContainer">
    <h1>Chooze the correct animal baby names!</h1>
    <div class="question"></div>
    <ul class="choiceList"></ul>
    <div class="quizMessage"></div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <div class="nextButton">Next Question</div><br/>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it works but the answers are still hidden

Comment: @QanBan I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: @QanBan No problem. Glad to help